# In SpriteKit, didEndContact occurs even though the sprites are still overlapping

Tags: events, sprite-kit

Why? I can clearly see the two sprites are overlapping! I am killing myself for hours and hours over having the contacts precise and consistent, but can't find a way to do it. Either the didBeginContact or didEndContact is triggered in the wrong time. Does anyone have a consistent solution for this? I tried changing the anchorPoints to various positions (instead of (0.5, 0.5) I tried other values, like (0.5, 0)), but that seems to have messed all the things up pretty badly. I can't set sprites to have physicsBody rectangle based, because I have non-rectangular sprites (obviously). So my sprites' physicsBody-s are mostly texture based. I can see with my own two eyes that sprites are still overlapping and haven't ended the contact, and the event still triggers!!! Why is this happening? I have the scene being the contact delegate and everything else is properly connected. The sprites (let's call them SKSpriteNode A and SKSpriteNode B) that collide are on the scene and have contact bitmasks set properly for each other. The scene is the only contact delegate for the physicsWorld, so only the scene can trigger and go in the event handler, so I know it is working - at least some of the time. Code in scene:

```
-(void) didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    NSLog(@"didEndContact occured!");
}
```

I have my custom class StaticLevelElement set so it extends SKSpriteNode:

```
@interface StaticLevelElement : SKSpriteNode
```

The B has been set as such StaticLevelElement with a triangular image:

```
StaticLevelElement * B = [StaticLevelElement spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"triangle"];
```

I tried to set the B's physicsBody to have texture based physicsBody:

```
B.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"triangle"] size:B.size];
```

And while the sprites A and B are still colliding and overlapping, the didEndContact occurs! I don't want it triggered when the sprites are still overlapping! How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should put your code by the question so we could look what is wrong.

Comment: Hello, the only question is "When does the didEndContact exactly occur"? I tried to elaborate and not to go to deep in code, because it can only make the question obscure. Thanks for downvoting though....

Comment: I will never understand people on Stackoverflow who give a negative to a question - probably under ANY circumstance. If I knew what is the solution to a problem, I wouldn't ask the question in the first place. I just stated my problem in hope that someone else - who in other case could be exactly me - could give me a quick help because he/she had the same problem, and had succesfuly solved it, and wants to share this lost time with other people. I would never expect to get a push off from some people that think they know "how the problem should be posed" ...... people huh?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use the texture based physicsBody, but either the polygon based, or rectangle based physicsBody.

Comment: yes, but isn't it easier to use texture based body and not having to deal with polygons, and also to have more pixel-perfect collision (contact)??

Comment: I read somewhere that texture based body has a bug in XCode, actually SpriteKit altogether and it is that physicsBody gets flipped vertically (or horizontally, I can't remember exactly) in the sprite images atlas, so this causes the problem that you describe. Try to google it up and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that!